# g++ returning errors when i try to use an alias of a pointer

Tags: c++, pointers, nodes

i'm trying to create a variable that is an alias of a Node pointer.

so far i have tried the following syntaxes:

```
node* _p = &p;
```

&

```
node* &_p = p;
```

whenever i attempt to call a class function (i.e. _p->getdata()) or even reference use the alias at all (if (_p==NULL)) i get an error that states:

```
error: expected primary-expression before ‘;’ token
             node* newnode = _p;
```

i have also tried putting * or & before _p when i call it, but it doesn't help.

note: i'm compiling using g++

a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example (i think):
the errors occur inside the insert function of the list class...

```
class node{
private:
    int data;
    node* next;
    int mark;
public:
    node(int d = 0, node* n = NULL){
        data = d;
        next = n;
        mark = 0;
    }
    int getdata(){return data;}
    node* getnext(){return next;}
    int getmark(){return mark;}
    void setdata(int x){data = x;}
    void setnext(node* x){next = x;}
    void setmark(int x){mark = x;}
};
class list{
private:
    node* L1; //head pointers to list1, list2, and freelist.
    node* L2;
    node* free;
    node* front;
public:
    list(){
        front = new node();  //generate free list (empty)
        free = front;
        L1 = NULL;
        L2 = NULL;
        node* p = free;
        for (int i = 1; i < 10; i++){
            p -> setnext(new node());
            p = p -> getnext();
        }
        delete p;
    }

    void insert(int a, int x){
        if (free == NULL) {
            cout << a << " is full. can't insert " << x << " into the list." << endl;
            return;
        }
        if (a == 1) node* &list = L1;
        else if (a == 2) node* &list = L2;
        else {
            cout << "not a valid list";
            return;
        }
        if (list == NULL){
            list = free;
            free = free -> getnext();
            list -> setdata(x);
            list -> setnext(NULL);
        }
        else {
            node* p = list;
            while (p -> getnext() != NULL) {p = p -> getnext();}
            p -> setnext(free);
            free = free -> getnext();
            p -> getnext() -> setnext(NULL);
            p -> getnext() -> setdata(x);
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] of something that gives this error.

Comment: If `p` is a pointer to `node`, try `node* _p = p;`

Comment: node* &list = L1;
list = list->getnext();

this second line is an example from my actual code, chris.

Comment: Knoep, when i use 
node*_p = p;
that is a brand new pointer. when i change the value of _p, i also wish p to change

Comment: You can define a reference to a pointer like this `node*& _p = p`. However, this seems strange. Are you sure, there is no better way to achieve whatever you want to achieve? Edit: I see that you tried this. This is the correct syntax. If you are getting errors, then because of something else.

Comment: The appropriate code to reproduce this should be edited into the question rather than left as a comment. However, please read that link more carefully. That code doesn't follow the "complete" part. We're not after a small part of your real code, nor the entire thing. An MCVE is much more workable and useful to everyone involved.

Comment: i edited the post to include a better example chris. thank you

Comment: Your variable `list` has the same name as your class.

Comment: If you declare a variable inside an `if` or `else` it's not in scope outside of that block. `list` is a terrible name for your class, given that you likely have `using namespace std;` in your code based on your usage of `cout` and not `std::cout`.

Comment: ur right knoep, for some reason i thought since i was inside the class that it didnt matter. thank you chris and knoep, and sorry for the stupid post. first post...

Comment: And your code is far from minimal... There are many lines not useful to understand the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In

```
if (a == 1) node* &list = L1;
else if (a == 2) node* &list = L2;
```

`list` is scoped within the `if` and the `else if`. It does not exist anywhere else. Here is the code with braces to make the problem more obvious:

```
if (a == 1) 
{
    node* &list = L1;
}
else if (a == 2) 
{
    node* &list = L2;
}
```

Since a reference can only be seated at initialization, you will have to move the logic somewhere else. The structure of your code does not make this easy.

Fortunately it does not appear that you need this to be a reference. Use a regular pointer here.

```
    node* list;
    if (a == 1) list = L1;
    else if (a == 2) list = L2;
```

## Edit

As pointed out by Retired Ninja in the comments, `list` *does* need to be a reference. In this case we have to take care of the problem of only being able to seat a reference once by using a function to select the correct list:

```
node* & getList(int a)
{
    if (a == 1)
    {
        return L1;
    }
    else if (a == 2)
    {
        return L2;
    }
    else
    {
        throw std::runtime_error("not a valid list");
    }
}
```

Note the exception thrown on failure. This is best handled somewhere below `insert` because `insert` is in no position to deal with it properly.

The revised initialization looks like

```
node* &list = getList(a);
```

now `list` is scoped by the function, seated only once and still a reference.